# How to query distinct with order by?

Tags: mysql

The following is the data inside the bids table.

```
id, user_id, amount
1, 2, 100
2, 3, 200
3, 2, 200
4, 2, 200
```

I want to query the unique `user_id` and `amount` of the user. Also, it needs to be `desc` of the amount. (query distinct with the order by)

The result should be something like the following...

```
id, user_id, amount
2, 3, 200
3, 2, 200
```

I try distinct with order by like the following

```
SELECT distinct user_id, amount FROM bids order by amount desc
```

And the result was duplicated with the user_id like the following

```
id, user_id, amount
1, 2, 100
2, 3, 200
3, 2, 200
```

How can I query `user_id` to be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the other values (e.g. `id`) from the first row with the highest `amount` for each `user_id`, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to filter out rows which have the same or lower amounts but a higher `id` value:

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM bids b1
LEFT JOIN bids b2 ON b2.user_id = b1.user_id AND b2.amount >= b1.amount AND b2.id > b1.id
WHERE b2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY b1.amount DESC
```

Output:

```
id  user_id     amount
2   3           200
4   2           200
```

If you don't care about the other values in the row, you can simply use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(amount) AS amount
FROM bids
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Output:

```
user_id     amount
2           200
3           200
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33b781/10)

Answer (score 2):

Using [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) and [MAX](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/)

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(amount) FROM bids GROUP BY user_id order by MAX(amount) desc
```